# Why isn't fetched formdata working when submit is?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, fetch-api

I have an html page with a form. When i submit the data with form.submit() everthing works fine. When I try to use fetch the server outputs the info as undefined

Client:

```
<form id="form" action="/submit-reservation" method="POST"> 
      <label for="name">Surname:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="address"><br>
      <label for="town">Town/City:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="town"><br>
      <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
      <center>
        <a onclick="form.submit();" class="button">Submit</a>
        <a onclick="fetch('/submit-reservation', { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form) });" class="button">Submit</a>
      </center>
</form>
```

Server:

```
app.post("/submit-reservation", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end();
});
```

form.submit() returns: { name: '', address: '', town: 'ASDF', email: '' }

fetch returns: {}

I checked to see if the formdata was correct on the client and it was.

Edit: Here is my code after the solution

```
<form id="form" action="/submit-reservation" method="POST"> 
      <label for="name">Surname:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="address"><br>
      <label for="town">Town/City:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="town"><br>
      <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
      <center>
        <a onclick="fetch('/submit-reservation', { method: 'POST', body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)) });" class="button">Submit</a>
      </center>
</form>
```

Comment: Open network tab and see if the body is properly sent

Comment: @Konrad I don't really know what I'm looking for but I found that the Sec-Fetch-Dest is "empty" on the fetch but is "document" on the submit

Comment: Uhh, please show the actual `fetch()` code as that's probably where the issue is.  If you do it right, it will work the same as the form submit.

Comment: @jfriend00 var formData = new FormData(form); fetch('/submit-reservation', { method: 'POST', body: formData });

Comment: Please put the `fetch()` code into your question where everyone will see it.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to do that.  Also, please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as that would be helpful here to include enough info to know how to reproduce the issue.  For example, in the code in your comment, it doesn't show what `formData` is.

Comment: jfriend00 the code is basically the same that is in the question. I don't know what you mean by what the formdata is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData ?

Comment: @Konrad - OK, that's was a bit hidden.  Got it now.

Comment: @jfriend00 the code is in the question `new FormData(form)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form` element has no `enctype` attribute so it defaults to encoding data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

A `FormData` object will be encoded as `multipart/form-data`.

You need to either:

- Replace `FormData` with `URLSearchParams` (which will be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).
- Add body parsing middleware that supports `multipart/form-data` to your server-side code.